# AWS SES emails to Gmail accounts flagged as phishing and delayed by 4 minutes

Tags: email, aws-lambda, gmail, amazon-ses, phishing

I'm using AWS SES in a Lambda function to send emails. When the email is sent to an Outlook address, or without an attachment to a Gmail address, it is received immediately.

However, when I send an email containing an attachment (in our case an Excel file), the emails are received almost exactly 4 minutes late every time.

I believe that Gmail is flagging our emails with attachments as phishing attempts, as mentioned [in this post](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/05/early-detection-of-phishing-via-delayed-delivery.html).

I have enabled SPF, DKIM and DMARC for my domain. Any idea what else I could try to fix this?

This is what our emails look like:
[image: delayed email screenshot]

Update: This only happens with Excel files. When I send this as a csv file, it is sent immediately.

Comment: Just an update - now, sometimes the emails are received immediately, and sometimes they still take 4 minutes. Maybe it has to do with building up a good reputation?

Comment: Share header of the mail received. With this information it can't be examined.